# Store a combination of texts and variables in a single variable

Tags: abap

I am doing a program in ABAP to display system date in differed formats like DDMMYYYY and YYYYDDMM.

The snippet is :

```
WRITE: / 'DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS',SY-DATUM+6(2),'.',SY-DATUM+0(4),'.',SY-DATUM+4(2).
```

which produces this output :

```
DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS 27 . 2007 . 07
```

Is it possible to store `DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS 27 . 2007 . 07` in a variable say `c` so that when I write the code `WRITE : c.` it outputs `DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS 27 . 2007 . 07`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the character string operator [`&&`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_operators.htm) to join texts and variables :

```
DATA: date_text TYPE c LENGTH 10.
date_text = sy-datum+6(2) && '.' &&
            sy-datum+0(4) && '.' &&
            sy-datum+4(2).
WRITE: / 'DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS',
         date_text.
```

And the output will be:

```
DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS 17.2019.07
```

PS: for WRITE, you can add [`NO-GAP`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapwrite-.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_3@3@) to each element so that the extra space is removed:

```
WRITE: / 'DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS',
         sy-datum+6(2) NO-GAP,
         '.'           NO-GAP,
         sy-datum+0(4) NO-GAP,
         '.'           NO-GAP,
         sy-datum+4(2) NO-GAP.
```

Output will be like above.

Comment: There are also the [string templates](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_templates.htm): `date_text = |{ sy-datum+6(2) }.{ sy-datum+0(4) }.{ sy-datum+4(2) }|.` There are predefined date formats in ABAP systems, for instance choose the user date format: `date_text = |{ sy-datum DATE = USER }|`.

Answer (score 1):

A handy approach for stuff like this is using [string templates](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenstring_templates.htm):

```
DATA(lv_date) = |{ sy-datum+6(2) }.{ sy-datum+0(4) }.{ sy-datum+4(2) }|.
WRITE: / |DATE IN DDYYYYMM FORMAT IS { lv_date }|.
```